# Firechat - Can't send messages

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I have a [Firechat](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/docs/) implementation that initializes properly but when logged in you can create and enter rooms but the messages go nowhere. I've built functions to handle the sending of messages but I don't think it's connecting the FirechatUI and Firechat objects correctly to the Firebase database.

```
function initChat(user) {
    var room = '';
    var db = firebase.database().ref("chat");
    var chat = new FirechatUI(db, document.getElementById('firechat'));
    var api = chat._chat;
    console.log(api);
    api.setUser(user.uid, user.displayName, function(user) {
        api.resumeSession();
    });

    chat.setUser(user.uid, user.displayName, function(user) {
        chat.resumeSession();
    });

    api.on('message-add', function(messagedRoom, messageContent) {
        console.log('Sent message to room: '+messagedRoom.id+' with the content "'+messageContent+'"');
        api.sendMessage(messagedRoom.id, messageContent, 'default');
    });

    api.on('room-enter', function(enteredRoom) {
        api.enterRoom(enteredRoom.id);
        room = enteredRoom.id;
    });

    api.on('room-exit', function(exitedRoom) {
        api.leaveRoom(exitedRoom.id);
        room = '';
    });

    isInitialized = true;
}
```

The "message-add" event never gets triggered but the "room-enter" and "room-exit" events do.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I tried to create new app with firebase and deploy your code.

**Database**
I'm choose **Realtime database**
[image]

You don't need to create tables, you should setup database rules. In my example I set up **true** for read|write
[image]

Then we can go to our deployed application, log-in and try to create chat and post messages.
[image]

All works, and if we try to login from another account - all data exists.
[image]

Resume: You should setup database rules.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [documentation](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/docs)... when calling to `api.on()` this only binds the event, but does not execute anything. as the above function `initChat()` looks alike, it is even questionable where the other events may come from. you need to first join a room and then send a message into that room, in order to have event `message-add` fired. also the [data-structure](https://firechat.firebaseapp.com/docs/#data_structure) & [security rules](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firechat/blob/master/rules.json) could play a role; eg.

```
"$roomId": {
    ...
    // a list of users that may read messages from this room.
    "authorizedUsers": {
        ".write": "(auth != null) && (!data.exists() || root.child('moderators').hasChild(auth.uid) || data.hasChild(auth.uid))"
    }
}
```

unless `moderators` or `"$roomId/authorizedUsers"` does not have the relevant user `key` added, there is no reason for an event being fired. a `key` entry in there is equal a subscription for messages.

Comment: The rules are set true for everyone to read and write. Do I need to setup the database first or will it auto add those tables and columns as messages and rooms are added?